# pysvn Client().diff usage

Tags: python, svn, python-2.6

I want to create script, which will compare same file - but from two different branches.

For this - I found `pyscv`module, I want use `diff` method from it.

But, if I create script like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pysvn

client = pysvn.Client()

diff_text = client.diff (tmp_path='/tmp', url_or_path='https://url_to_brach_1.com/properties.file', \
url_or_path2='https://url_to_brach_2.com/properties.file')
```

I got error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./svn_1.py", line 11, in
>   
>       url_or_path2='https://url_to_brach_2.com/properties.file')
>   pysvn._pysvn.ClientError: A path under version control is needed for
>   this operation

URL *https://url_to_brach_2.com/properties.file* exist, and `client.cat()` or `client.ls()` works for both url's in this example.

**Python** 2.6